# Should I use ANOVA or paired t-test?

Tags: anova, t-test

For my statistical analysis, I want to find out:

If there is a statistical significant difference in PM2.5 levels in 2019 and in 2020**.

If there is a statistical significant difference in PM10 levels in 2019 and in 2020**.

If there is a statistical significant difference in NO2 levels in 2019 and in 2020**.

If there is a statistical significant difference in O3 levels in 2019 and in 2020**.

So as you can see, I'm not comparing the pollutants with each other – there's no reason to do so in my study. I'm just comparing 2019 and 2020, using 4 different pollutants. Therefore I am confused as to whether I should use an **ANOVA** (would it not just end up comparing NO2 against O3, PM10, PM2.5 and vice versa?) or if I should do four **paired t-tests**?

(I'm aware their are issues with doing time series, about things being autocorrelated and all that, but for the sake of this analysis I don't need to get into deep complexity. I'm just doing a simple analysis!)

** It's not for the entire year, just for Jan, Feb, March, April but I don't need to break it up by month, I can just compare 2019 to 2020.If there is an easy way to to break it down by month, please do mention, but it's not necessary!

Comment: Running the a t-test for each of the 4 components will provide more information than conducting the anova.  Be careful with the paired sample assumption.  Does every single data point collected in 2019 have a matching one in 2020?

Comment: Well i can't guarantee the data point is taken at the exact same air quality station in 2019 vs 2020, but I do have a data point representing each day for both years. One other question - I am also trying to create a 'baseline' air quality, by averaging the data from 2017, 2018, and 2019 together. So one day is actually an average of 3 data points from each of those years. And comparing the 'combined 3 yr' data with the '2020' data. Would you still consider these data points paired? Or not, because one of the categories is made up of averages from 3 yrs?

Comment: If the hypothesis is 2020's daily air quality is different from the historical average (ie the prior 3 years).  Then I would accept the paired data assumption and perform a paired test, provide the number and type of sensors were comparable across the timeframe(you are going have to made an assumption or correct for this). Be clear when reporting the analysis what your assumptions and your methodology was.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! really appreciate it

Comment: There is no reason to assume that measurements for each of the four pollutants has the same variability. Therefore it seems simpler to do four paired t tests.